# Using EF in WCF REST service - SerializationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, wcf

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

This is the error i got, when i try to get data with FK from DB using EF.

This is my Context class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

        public DbSet<TypeCar> TypeCarList { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Car> CarList{ get; set; }
}


    [DataContract]
    public class TypeCar
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int TypeCarId{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string typeName{ get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Car
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string carName{ get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual TypeCar FK_Car{ get; set; }
    }
```

This is my IService interface:

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "getCars",
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    List<Car> getCars();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "getTypeCars",
      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    List<TypeCar> getTypeCars();


}
```

And this is my Service1 class:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{


    public List<Avtomobil> getCars()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            return db.CarList.ToList();
        }
    }
    public List<TypeCar> getTypeCars()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            return db.TypeCarList.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

When i call REST method getTypeCars it works like it should. But when I call getCars method (with FK) it throws given exception (Serialization Exception). I tried the same with other entities, but always the same (exception when entity with FK is being called).

EDIT:
And if i delete "virtual" word from attribute FK_TypeCar, the exception is not thrown, but the value of FK_TypeCar is null.

Comment: have you tried to set [Serializable] in the top of the class?

Comment: I did, still the same.

Comment: @Tadej I wouldn't use entites for json. They got serialized and the object graph can be very long. Use Dtos instead. To your issue: I would guess, wcf tries to access `FK_Car`, but your context is allready closed. Try to fetch `FK_Car` before.

Comment: mm sorry i don't have used so much WCF in REST mode (i suggest you WebAPI instead) .. but be sure the problem is not the Reference Looping when it try to serialize in JSON the Query Entities

Comment: @Rabban When i use breakpoint on returning the list, i can see there is full list of Cars (with correct TypeCar objects). But when i press F10 (step over) the method starts again from beginning, and again there are correct objects on return, but the exception is thrown after i press F10.

Comment: I can only recommend to use Dtos instead of entities. Its a really bad idea to use entities in wcf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rabban is correct -  you should be using separate objects to return the data via EF and then convert these to your DataContract objects. Here's one of many reasons why:

Currently you have created your EF entities with a `virtual` property on `Car` for the `TypeCar` but no corresponding `ICollection<Car>` in `TypeCar` for the one-to-many relationship back to `Car`. So the relationship is not fully described. If you were to do so then the WCF DataContractJsonSerializer would throw a SerializationException because of a circular reference anyway. So in order to have EF entities that fully describe your underlying schema and enable you to pass objects back via WCF you will have to create separate DTOs.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use DTOs. A bit more coding, but probably better solution than keep on using whole entity in class.